# How to deploy and activate SP2010 wsp to SP2016

Tags: sharepoint-server, feature, branding

I am working on a project where we have to migrate SP2010 to SP2016. We have some SP2010 wsp for activating branding feature.

Can we deploy SP2010 WSP directly to SP2016?

I tried to deploy it on SP2016 but while activating feature its not working and giving error File not found.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how your solution is created. Basically you need to check the code, change things like namespace and test again in your new farm.

Something may be helpful to you:https://www.techmikael.com/2016/04/considerations-when-upgrading-wsps-from.html

Comment: the wsp contains branding feature , there is no SQL connection. And we dont have the source code . so I dissassembled it and saw that it is for branding.

Answer (score 0):

If the solution contains branding, almost certainly yes you will need to update the solution as it won't be v15 compatible.

In addition, your branding will likely break as you upgrade the site from v14.5 in SharePoint 2013 to v15 prior to updating to SharePoint 2016 (provided you're doing a database attach upgrade; if doing a content migration, you still need to address your branding).

Answer (score 0):

I have been dealing with this type of migration for +5 years, and the best practice to be able to reinstall a wsp from an earlier version of SharePoint to a newer version is you have a SharePoint 2016 Development Farm, following this steps:

(1) restore the Databases (WSS_Contents) from the 2010 version to the SharePoint 2016 Database;

(2) open the Projects through Visual Studio, updating the Build version of the .NET Framework;

(3) recompiling and deploy the WSPs pointing to this the new address of this Farm (in SharePoint 2016).

With this practice, it is possible to update several resources, mainly bindings of DLLs belonging to the SharePoint platform from version 2010 to version 2016.